# Is it possible to move the cursor to the end of the TextField in the textfield_tags package?

Tags: flutter, dart, jtextfield

I've been having this problem for several days. I implemented the package, but I want to adapt it to my requirements. Each of the tags should be seen on the screen, one below the other, vertically.
The problem is that the cursor is always at the end and it is not right.

I've already tried:

```
textController.selection ... etc
```

But it didn't work for me or at least not in the way I required. Any ideas or suggestions?

https://pub.dev/packages/textfield_tags